Is there a way of sorting a telerik listview datasource by the field and then by content of the field
I have a Telerik core mvc listview. I have a search functionality on my page which filters the datasource on 2 fields as follows.
 var filters = [];

 let searchArray = query. Split(" ");

 filters.push({ field: "FirstName", operator: "contains", value: searchArray[0] });

 let nameFilter = [];

 for (let i = 0; i < searchArray.length; i++) {
     nameFilter.push({ field: "FullName", operator: "contains", value: searchArray[i] });
 }

 dataSource.filter({
     logic: "and",
     filters: [
         { logic: "or", filters: filters },
         { logic: "and", filters: nameFilter }
     ]
 });

I need for the result to be sorted in a way that the FirstName is displayed first and then the result of FullName. When searching for 'James', 'James Arthur' should be displayed before 'Arthur James'. Please help.
I tried filtering first by FirstName and then by Fullname but this didn't work. I'm not sure what is the default sorting of a datasource...

It would be nice to know how the data is shown/populated before and after using your filtering code
